# Javascript - Access a nested property on an object from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object like this

```
{
  metadata: {
    correlationId: 'b24e9f21-6977-4553-abc7-416f8ed2da2d',
    createdDateTime: '2021-06-15T16:46:24.247Z'
  }
}
```

and I have an array of the properties I wanna access

```
[metadata, correlationId]
```

how can I dynamically access the property on the object?
like

```
keys.forEach((key) => {
  object[key][key2] ???
})
```

it needs to be dynamic since I don't know how deep we need to access the object

Comment: What is your intended output value to look like?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution without recursion:

```js
const myObj = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: "I'm the target"
        }
    }
}
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let result = myObj;
for (const key of keys) {
    result = result[key];
}
console.log(result);
```

Or with recursion:

```js
const finder = (obj, keys, index = 0) => {
    const result = obj[keys[index++]];
    
    if (!result) {
        return obj;
    }
    return finder(result, keys, index);
}

console.log(finder(myObj, keys));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty similar to [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/9515207), except with one fewer step - you already have the keys you need in the form of an array. `.reduce` and access the next nested value in each iteration.

```js
const obj = {
  metadata: {
    correlationId: 'b24e9f21-6977-4553-abc7-416f8ed2da2d',
    createdDateTime: '2021-06-15T16:46:24.247Z'
  }
};
const keys = ['metadata', 'correlationId'];

const result = keys.reduce((a, key) => a[key], obj);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea to solve your problem. Tell me, if is ok for you.

```js
let x = {
  metadata: {
    correlationId: 'b24e9f21-6977-4553-abc7-416f8ed2da2d',
    createdDateTime: '2021-06-15T16:46:24.247Z'
  }
}

let fun = x => typeof x === 'string' ? console.log(x) : Object.keys(x).map( y => fun(x[y]));

fun(x);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's looking for recurrent algorithm to handle any level of depth.

Comment: ah ok, I understood, wait a minute.

Comment: check this code, is it better? Now it is recursive.